# Excel find and remove duplicate row pairs that have switched values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a list of rows that match account info by similarity

John | Bonham  | 123 Main St          | (555)555-5512 |   **-1-**
John | Bonham  | 854 Local St        | (555)555-1111 |   **-1-**
John | Bonham  | 123 Main St          | (555)555-5512 |   
John | Bonham  | 121 Mission St     | (555)555-1234 | 
John | Brown    | 555 Some Ave     | (555)555-2323 |
John | Bell         | 434 Uptown Blvd  | (555)555-8888 |
John | Bennet    | 666 Side Ave      | (555)555-2323 |
John | Baker      | 484 Downy St      | (555)555-8888 |
John | Bonham  | 854 Local St        | (555)555-1111 |   **-2-**
John | Bonham  | 123 Main St          | (555)555-5512 |  **-2-**
Jay   | Carter      | 123 Main St          | (555)555-5512 |

As you can see I've already found the John Bonham accounts with the first instances.  Is there an easy way I can remove the second instances of the accounts with Excel or Google Sheets?

Edit: I don't want to just remove duplicates.  As you can see now, there are two unique matches fo John Bonham that I want to keep.  The 123 Main matches the 854 Local and the 121 Mission.  I just want to remove the second instance of the 854 Local

Edit2: I guess I should have mentioned, there is no unique data.  Phone numbers do not belong to one account only.

Comment: On Excel Data --> Remove Duplicates.

Comment: Hey Scott, so there are actually duplicates that I want to keep.  I.e. there might be a second match of John Bonham.  Ex. John Bonham 123 Main St and John Bonham 233 Side st..  I don't want want to remove that second instance of John Bonham, I just want to remove it if 2 rows BOTH contain the same info as an earlier two rows.

Comment: You can specify which columns are compared so you would compare three or four and it will only remove those that are identical in those rows specified.  In your example if you choose the first two columns then only the last two lines would be removed those marked with a 2.

Comment: IF your phone numbers can only belong to one person, you could also just remove duplicates based on phone number since the phone number would then be acting as a unique key identifier for the person.

Comment: Alas, the phone numbers are not unique.  Sometimes there are multiple employees at the same company which use the same phone number.  Basically no column has truly unique data, it's all or nothing.

Comment: Then test on all of them, then only truly unique rows will remain.  The whole line would need to be identical for it to be deleted.

Comment: Hey Scott but if you see the revised example I put above, I don't want to remove duplicate rows.  Some duplicates I want to keep.  I want to  remove two rows if they match the exact same data as another two rows.

Comment: What is the difference between row 3 and row 10?  Why should one be removed and the other not?

Comment: Because I'm merging these accounts.  I need to know to merge 3 with 4 because they share the same name (that's a gross over exageration, I'm not actually merging accounts just by name).  If I delete 3, I don't know that it has matching info with 4.  I want  to remove 9 and 10 because I already merged those accounts (1 and 2) and it's huge waste of time to look them up and realize they've been merged into a new account.  -- Keep in mind my actual list is 6,000+ accounts

Comment: You are asking a computer to think and interpolate.  Computers are dumb and only do what is told.  There is no way to do this outside programming for every instance.  The code would take more time than going through the list manually.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you can use remove duplicates option present in data menu on column with phone no.

Comment: Hey Varun, is there a way to make that work with my edit?

Comment: yes . in that case you should use remove duplicates option on complete data .
when u will use remove duplicate option u will get menu with checkmark on an all columns. u need to select all columns and apply .

Answer (score 0):

With Google Spreadsheets you can use:

```
=unique(A1:C6)
```

Or a function:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
}
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length,  newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
```

}

Comment: Hey Ed, is there a similar formula that would work with my edit?